# Query equivalent to two group by's without a subquery?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a report on User ACL's. We use MYSQL and my we're prohibited from using subqueries for performance reasons. The goal is to turn this:

```
    --------------------------------
    | userName | folderID | roleID |
    --------------------------------
    | gronk    |     1    |    1   |
    | gronk    |     2    |    2   |
    | gronk    |     4    |    2   |
    | tbrady   |     1    |    2   |
    | jedelman |     1    |    1   |
    | jedelman |     2    |    1   |
    | mbutler  |     1    |    2   |
    | mbutler  |     2    |    2   |
    | bill     |     1    |    3   |
    | bill     |     2    |    3   |
    | bill     |     3    |    3   |
    | bill     |     4    |    3   |
    --------------------------------
```

Into this:

```
    ------------------------
    | Lowest Role | Number |
    ------------------------
    |      1      |    2   |
    |      2      |    2   |
    |      3      |    1   |
    ------------------------
```

I can see how to do it with a subquery. The inner query would do a group by on userName with a min(roleID). Then the outer query would do a group by on the lowest role and count(*). But I can't see how to do it without a subquery.

Also, if it helps I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/381fe8/3) that has the data above.

Comment: 'prohibited from using subqueries for performance reason' I despair for humanity

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a left join:

```
select UFM.roleID, count(distinct UFM.userName) 
from UserFolderMembership UFM
left join UserFolderMembership UFM2 on
    UFM.userName = UFM2.userName and
    UFM.roleID > UFM2.roleID
where
    UFM2.userName is null
group by 
    UFM.roleID
```